# Why the lock object and condition queue object must be the same object?

Tags: java, concurrency, wait

I find this in "Java concurrency in practice"

> There is an important threeway relationship in a
>   condition wait involving locking, the wait method, and
>   a condition predicate. The condition predicate involves
>   state variables, and the state variables are guarded
>   by a lock, so before testing the condition
>   predicate, we must hold that lock. **The lock object
>   and the condition queue object (the object on which
>   wait and notify are invoked)must also be the same
>   object.**

This is the example code:

```
abstract class BaseBoundedBuffer<V> {
    private final V[] buf;
    private int tail;
    private int head;
    private int count;
    protected BaseBoundedBuffer(int capacity) {
        this.buf = (V[]) new Object[capacity];
    }
    protected synchronized final void doPut(V v) {
        buf[tail] = v;
        if (++tail == buf.length)
            tail = 0;
        ++count; }
    protected synchronized final V doTake() {
        V v = buf[head];
        buf[head] = null;
        if (++head == buf.length)
            head = 0;
        --count;
        return v; }
    public synchronized final boolean isFull() {
        return count == buf.length;
    }
    public synchronized final boolean isEmpty() {
        return count == 0;
    }
}

public class BoundedBuffer<V> extends BaseBoundedBuffer<V> {
    // CONDITION PREDICATE: not-full (!isFull())
    // CONDITION PREDICATE: not-empty (!isEmpty())
    public BoundedBuffer(int size) { super(size); }

    // BLOCKS-UNTIL: not-full
    public  synchronized  void put(V v) throws InterruptedException {
        while (isFull())
            wait();
        doPut(v);
        notifyAll();
    }

    // BLOCKS-UNTIL: not-empty
    public  synchronized  V take() throws InterruptedException {
        while (isEmpty())
            wait();
        V v = doTake();
        notifyAll();
        return v;
    } 
}
```

The lock object and condition queue object both are `this`.

If I write the code in this way:

```
public class BoundedBuffer<V> extends BaseBoundedBuffer<V> {
    // CONDITION PREDICATE: not-full (!isFull())
    // CONDITION PREDICATE: not-empty (!isEmpty())
    private Object conditionQueue = new Object();

    public BoundedBuffer(int size) { super(size); }

    // BLOCKS-UNTIL: not-full
    public  synchronized  void put(V v) throws InterruptedException {
        while (isFull())
            conditionQueue.wait();
        doPut(v);
        conditionQueue.notifyAll();
    }

    // BLOCKS-UNTIL: not-empty
    public  synchronized  V take() throws InterruptedException {
        while (isEmpty())
            conditionQueue.wait();
        V v = doTake();
        conditionQueue.notifyAll();
        return v;
    } 
}
```

The lock object is `this` and the condition queue object is `conditionQueue`.

The lock object is different from condition queue object and I don't figure out why this way is not good.

So anyone could tell me why the lock object and condition queue object must be the same object?

Comment: We've had this before. There is no 'condition queue' in Java. 'Condition predicate' is acceptable.

Comment: @EJP , The title of 14.2 is "Using condition queue", so I thought 'condition queue' is an Java conception.

Answer (score 1):

Self answer.

I got the point why lock object and condition queue object must be the same object.

`condtionQueue.wait()` only release the lock guarded by `conditionQueue`. But in this condition, we except when the thread wait, the thread should release the lock guarded by `this`.

So the lock object and condition queue object must be the same object. So that when thread wait, the lock guraded by lock object will be released.